# C++: the best structure for implementing Vector and Matrix classes

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I want to implement `Vector` and `Matrix` classes in C++, such that `Vector` and `Matrix` objects are able to be multiplied. There are the following 2 structures that I could think of for their implementations:

1. Implement the template class `Vector` with `T*` type of data, and then define template class `Matrix` as an array of `Vector`s.
2. Implement the template class `Matrix` with `T**` type of data, and then inherit template class `Vector` as a `Matrix` with (number of columns = 1).

The disadvantage of the 1st approach is that, `Vector` class doesn't take care of column and row vectors and the vector-vector multiplications would be problematic, and in second approach, the `Vector` would be treated as a 2D Matrix with (number of columns =1) or `T**`.

What would be the best way to implement these 2 classes?
Thanks.

Comment: Neither approach is good. Matrices should be implemented as a *contiguous* array, i.e. a `T*` (or, more cleanly, a `std:vector<T>`). This gives you contiguous storage, and your `Matrix` class handles the index calculation.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend doing to much stuff with raw pointers, it can get really messy later on and is a nightmare to debug. I would use a generic vector

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<T>
```

so you can use different types if you need to. But if you are only dealing with number I wouldn't over-engineer it.

For the multiplication you can use operator overloading.
You could look at same already existing implementation and see if there is something that suits your needs. A quick google research gave me this:

[CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3613/A-generic-reusable-and-extendable-%20matrix-class)

If you find anything else feel free to add it to your question so nobody has to reinvent the wheel.